# xsd: abstract class collection

Tags: xml, xsd

I have xml files:

```
<Parent>
  <Child1 ... />
  <Child2 ... />
  ...
  <Child1 ... />
  <Child1 ... />
<Parent>
```

Where Clild1 and Child2 - childrens of Parent abstract class.

That is, the question was:
How to set a validation scheme for the collection that can have any number of elements different types?

Best regards!

Comment: Did you mean parent element and child elements? XML does not have a class hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, I did not say so, I mean a class structure - source of this xml. I thought it might be useful.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by class structure, but I went ahead and wrote out an example of what you might be looking for to validating your sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xs:element name="Parent">
  <xsl:complexType>
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Child1"/>
      <xs:element name="Child2"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

To illustrate how this works let's use a simplified version of your example input.

```
<Parent>
  <Child1 ... />
  <Child2 ... />
  <Child1 ... />
  <Child1 ... />
</Parent>
```

1. The validator looks at the first element.`<Parent>` is the first element so validates.
2. The validator then looks for the complex type inside of parent. It finds `<Child1>`. Since `<Child1>` is the first element in the `choice` block it validates.
3. The validator then looks for the `<Child2>` element. Since `<Child2>` is next it also validates.
4. The validator then looks at the next element. It is not `</Parent>` so the validator checks it against the `choice` block since it can occur an unlimited number of times as `maxOccurs=unbounded`.
5. The validator finds a `<Child1>` element which validates.
6. The validator looks for a `<Child2>` element which doesn't exist so it finishes the `choice` block.
7. The validator then looks at the next element. It is not `</Parent>` so the validator checks it against the `choice` block since it can occur an unlimited number of times as `maxOccurs=unbounded`.
8. The validator finds a `<Child1>` element which validates.
9. The validator then looks at the next element. It is `</Parent>` which validates.
10. The validator is done. The document validates successfully.

Since `minOccurs=0` this also allows for the case where there is `0` occurrences of a `<Child1>` or `<Child2>` element. XML schema elements inherit the properties of their parent elements unless explicitly declared. In this case, since we did not declare a minOccurs property for either `<Child1>` or `<Child2>` this is the equivalent of `<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Child1"/>` and `<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Child2"/>`.

Comment: Thank you for good answer! Thank on answer, on the attempt to decrypt question and for a detailed example, which put my brains in the place :)